# Assigned values to a variable in a class from Button click event outside. But returning zero as output from another button click

Tags: c#, class, button, methods

Here I have a variable in a class and trying to give input and get output from through buttons outside the class. But when I am creating new object to a class (button2), I am not getting output values given (button1).

```
    class dataconversion
    {

        public List<decimal> sample = new List<decimal>();

        public void dataconvert(List <decimal> transfer)
        {
            string filedata;
            Stream filestream;
            OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((filestream = opendialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(opendialog.FileName);
                    List<string> stringlist = new List<string>(filedata.Split(' ', '\n', '\t'));
                    stringlist = stringlist.Where(val => val != "").ToList();
                    List<decimal> decimallist = stringlist.ConvertAll(s => decimal.Parse(s));
                    transfer.AddRange(decimallist);
                }

            }

        }

    }

    public class methodacess
    {
        dataconversion dc = new dataconversion();

        public void sampleaccess()
        {
            dc.dataconvert(dc.sample);

        }

        public void messages()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dc.sample.Count.ToString());
        }

//output is giving only zeros.
   }
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        methodacess ma = new methodacess();
        ma.sampleaccess();
     }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        methodacess ma4 = new methodacess();
        ma4.messages();
    }

}
```

Comment: The two buttons create two completely separate and unrelated objects/instances of type `methodacess` (namely `ma` and `m4`). And those two `methodacess` objects each have completely separate and unrelated objects/instances of type `dataconversion` (`dc`). And those two `dataconversion` objects each have completely separate and unrelated objects/instances of type `List<decimal>` (`sample`). So when you cange the content of one `ma.dc.sample` then the number of items in `ma4.dc.sample` will not change and simply remain `0`.

Comment: Its hard to match the puzzle from your code. First, in your sample you create a new instance of *methodaccess* every time, so *sampleaccess* needs to be called before *messages*. Second it looks like an asp.net code to me. Thus each button handler will be executed in completely new Page class

Comment: @Corak - Thanks corak for elaborating drawbacks in my code. I was using separate objects and expecting to get output using one object from the input given from another object. Could you please suggest me the right way to deal with this kind of tailoring variables in one class with different methods outside the class and also in other classes.

Comment: @Raja -- I'm not sure about *the* right way to do it, but Enigmativity showed you *a* great way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line in `button4_Click`:

```
methodacess ma4 = new methodacess();
```

You are creating a brand new instance of `methodacess`.

In fact the one you created in `button1_Click` is not stored anywhere and is lost after the method exits.

So your call to `ma.sampleaccess();` is on a different instance to the call on `ma4.messages();` so no wonder there is no data.

Now, I don't like the way you've structured your classes. It's really a bit odd, but sticking with this structure here's how I would write it.

First, `dataconversion` - make it static with a single function that returns a new copy of the list.

```
public static class dataconversion
{
    public static List<decimal> dataconvert()
    {
        var filedata = "";
        using (var opendialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(opendialog.FileName))
                {
                    filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(opendialog.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
        return
            filedata
                .Split(' ', '\n', '\t')
                .Where(val => val != "")
                .Select(s => decimal.Parse(s))
                .ToList();
    }
}
```

Now, `methodaccess` - notice it now just holds the actual list of decimals:

```
public class methodacess
{
    List<decimal> data = new List<decimal>();

    public void sampleaccess()
    {
        data = dataconversion.dataconvert();
    }

    public void messages()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(data.Count.ToString());
    }
```

}

And finally your UI calling code:

```
private methodacess ma = new methodacess();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ma.sampleaccess();
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ma.messages();
}
```

Note that there is a single instance of `methodaccess`.

Comment: Thank you Enigmativity. Now I got better understanding on creating instances.

Comment: it almost worked. But now i am getting this error -  "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index" at                                                                  `'for (int j = 1; j < v.sample.count; j++)
            {
                v.iq[j] = (((v.sample[j] - v.background[j]) / v.tsh) - ((v.holder[j] - v.background[j]) / v.th));
                j = j + 1;
            }`

Comment: @Raja - Why are you incrementing `j` twice? Also, this code isn't in your question. This should be a new question - and you need to post the rest of the code because this isn't enough to work from.

Comment: website is not allowing to post a new question. It says I have to wait two days to post a new question.